# How to compare files at the same index from different directories

Tags: python, directory, iterator, listdir

I am trying to access data from two folders. I want to access file1d1 from directory1 while also accessing file1d2 from directory2 to compare the data within the files. After comparing file1d1 and file1d2, I want to then be able to compare file2d1 and file2d2 and so on. So far I've only been able to iterate through one directory at a time using this:

```
for file in os.listdir(directory):
filename = os.fsdecode(file)
        if filename.endswith(".txt"): 
            continue
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: Do both directories have exactly the same order of files? So, if you use `listdir` on both directories you can simply compare the first entry of both. Then, compare the second one and so on. Or is it different and you take a file from directory 1 and have to find the corresponding file in directory 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zip()` function, it returns an iterator of tuples based on the iterable objects.

```py
import os

dir1 = os.listdir("directory1")  # e.g., [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]
dir2 = os.listdir("directory2")  # e.g., [b1, b2, b3]

for (file1, file2) in zip(dir1, dir2):
    # Do your stuff
    print(file1 + " | " + file2)

# Output:
# a1 | b1
# a2 | b2
# a3 | b3
```

**Note that the iterator stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted.**

Comment: That worked! Thanks